# Can i load test Hbase table using Loadrunner?

Tags: hbase, performance-testing, loadrunner

I want load test newly configured hbase table which gets data from various other system. I am looking for a tool which can help get the stats(response times etc.). Can i do same with Loadrunner? I wonder, whether it supports as i don't see any protocol related to hbase on Loadrunner.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many paths to use LoadRunner to performance test Hbase.  What has your research on the topic suggested?   Before I provide solution sets I want to understand where your research has taken you and where you have been blocked

Comment: i have been searching for a way to load test hbase on google. There are many ways like using hbase inbuilt performance analyzing feature, open source tools like jmeter. Thought of Doing the same with Load runner, googled and didn't found helpful.

Comment: Here is the path.   LoadRunner supports some 30+ interfaces natively, plus the ability to built template solutions in a variety of languages and platforms, such as C# in Visual Studio.   The key on support is finding an interface match.  An example, LoadRunner supports exercising an ODBC interface, if an HBase ODBC driver exists then you have a match and support.   Likewise, if C/C#/VB libraries exist for Visual Studio and Hbase, then you can leverage the ability to build a user in Visual Studio.....and so forth.  #foundationskills #architecture #development

Comment: is it possible to connect hbase through ODBC protocol?

Comment: Well, LoadRunner supports ODBC....Does HBASe have an ODBC driver?  What does your research suggest?  If so, then how would you leverage your training to test this hypothesis?

Answer (score 1):

If your LoadRunner instance supports Java or C# scripting you can plug in [hbase-client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-client) for Java or [HBase.NET](https://hbasenet.codeplex.com/) for C#.

I'm not aware of any C SDK you could use.

---

Alternatively you can consider a free and open source tool, for example [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) to accomplish Hbase performance testing.

Out of box JMeter doesn't support Hadoop, however due to modular structure JMeter can be extended to support literally anything, take a look at [Hadoop Set](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HadoopSet/) of [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) project which provides test elements to conduct the load on HDFS and Hbase.

You can install the necessary plugins along with dependencies using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager Hadoop]

Comment: Jmeter is great option although their is a client requirement for Loadrunner.